# How do I deactivate all game objects in an array except ONE?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, I plan to make tutorials appear for my game. As in you press T to make the tutorial window appear and press Q and E to cycle through multiple tutorial images. The tutorial images are game objects. So, if I got 10 tutorial images.. and need only ONE of them active at a time (while the others are deactivated), how do I do it?

I have tried this:

`tutorialBubbles[]` is the array of game objects.

```
public GameObject[] tutorialBubbles; //delete the above one if we're going with multiple 
bool tutorialNeeded;

void checkIfTutorialNeeded() {
    
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
        {
            tutorialNeeded = true;
        }

        if(!tutorialNeeded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T)){

            tutorialBubbles[0].SetActive(false);
        }

        if (tutorialNeeded)
        {
            tutorialBubbles[0].SetActive(true);
            

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
            {
                tutorialBubbles[1].SetActive(false);

                for (int i = 2; i < tutorialBubbles.Length; i++)
                {
                    tutorialBubbles[i].SetActive(true);   
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The first element in an array is `[0]`, not `[1]`.

Comment: Ah. Yes. My bad. I fixed that now..

Answer (score 1):

You can define some integer values for demonstrate which ArrayID wont be inclueded. For example:

```
public GameObject[] tutorialBubbles; //delete the above one if we're going with multiple 
bool tutorialNeeded;
int exceptArrayId;
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
            {
                tutorialBubbles[1].SetActive(false);
                exceptArrayId = 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < tutorialBubbles.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(i == exceptArrayId)
                    {
                        tutorialBubbles[i].SetActive(false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tutorialBubbles[i].SetActive(false);
                    }
                    
                }
            }
```

I defined a int(exceptArrayId) for this example.

Comment: My idea is to have 10 tutorial bubbles... and basically make it like when you press T, the first one is open. After that, you need to press Q and E to move to previous and next tutorial bubbles. Each tutorial bubble is a game object in the array. 

I tried your code. Didn't work. The tutorial bubbles are NOT active in the hierarchy when the game starts. They are to be activated ONLY if the player presses a key... and only one at a time.